# Why is IconButton a stateless widget in Flutter, rather than being a stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

In the flutter documentation, it states

> "A stateless widget never changes. Icon, IconButton, and Text are examples of stateless widgets. Stateless widgets subclass StatelessWidget.
>
> A stateful widget is dynamic: for example, it can change its appearance in response to events triggered by user interactions or when it receives data. Checkbox, Radio, Slider, InkWell, Form, and TextField are examples of stateful widgets. Stateful widgets subclass StatefulWidget."

This is confusing to me, because an IconButton can change its appearance in response to events triggered by user interactions. I am not understanding the distinction between stateless and stateful given this example

when making a custom widget, I am unsure when to make it stateful or stateless

Answer (score 2):

`IconButton` might be stateless but it uses widgets that are stateful (`ButtonStyleButton` in this case). The state is held by `ButtonStyleButton` and `IconButton` is only a wrapper around it to make it easier to use, set default values or use the correct theme.

> when making a custom widget, I am unsure when to make it stateful or stateless

Always go for a `StatelessWidget` if you can. You only need `StatefulWidget` if you need to save something in the state (and use `setState`) or any other method of the `StatefulWidget` like `initState` for example. You could use `initState` to trigger an http call to an API only once when the widget is mounted for example.